# Bind a Gridview within a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have GridView2 within another GridView1.  I'm trying to populate it with the below code. 
GridView4 is a gridview I was using to test that is not nested within another gridview.  It populates with no problems.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
       { 
          string connectionString = "Data Source=MyConnection String";
          using (SqlConnection test = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
          {
             test.Open();
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID], [CTNum], [PRPNum], [DateEntered], [CurrentRFBDate], [CurrentRFBPRPDate], [CurrentRFPDate], [CurrentRFPPRPDate], [EnteredBy] FROM [PRPDateTracking]", test);

             SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             if (reader.HasRows)
             {
               GridView4.DataSource = reader;
               GridView4.DataBind();
               ((GridView)gvr.FindControl("GridView2")).DataSource = reader;
               ((GridView)gvr.FindControl("GridView2")).DataBind();

             }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not".
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 2):

If each row of parent gridview is associated with nested GridView then You can find the nested gridview in `RowDataBound` event like this

```
GridView gvr = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find the inner (child)gridview in the RowDataBound event of the parent grid view and bind values to the child gridview.

refer these links to get an good idea about nested grids

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685079/Nested-GridView-in-ASP-NET-using-Csharp